# MS Access: Parent relation in a subform

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2007

We use MS Access 2007 as a front-end to a SQLServer 2008-r2. In this database several tables have a column that references the address table:

```
Person
 - PersonId
 - Name
 - AddressId

Facility
 - FacilityId
 - Name
 - AddressId

Address
 - AddressId
 - Street
 - Number
 - City
```

Both person and facility have their own form on which the address should be visible and editable. Unfortunately MS Access subforms don't work well with this type of relationship. It does bind, but it does not refresh nor create an address and update the AddressId in the parent form. This can be somewhat fixed in code, but I am having a hard time making it stable.

What should I do? I came up with:

- Shove the address columns into the facility and person table.
- Create controls on the person and facility form and fill/save them with code.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, the update is usually from the parent to the child, not from the child to the parent.

Comment: I would be inclined to use a pop-out form for adding addresses and write back to the main form.

Comment: @Remou This is just naming. Normally a subform is used to list the many in a one-to-many relationship. These can then be browsed per item or in a long list. Thanks for the suggestion, seems like a good idea.